# How to create this sublime text syntax?

Tags: sublimetext

I am trying to create a simple sublime syntax where when the first word of a line is "DONE" the whole line turns to a different color.

For example:

```
- do this
DONE - do that      // this line turns green
- but also do this
```

My two questions are:
- How does one go about creating a ST syntax
- How would I create the above simple syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The most you could highlight is the region containing text. I don't know if that's what you are looking for. To do this would require defining a tmLanguage file and modifying you tmTheme file. The tmLanguage file describes a set of regular expressions for which a scope is applied to the text within ST. The tmTheme file takes the scopes applied, and applies some coloring. I'm not an expert on writing either of these files, so you may need to do some experimentation on your own.

For information on writing syntax files, see [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) and [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html). The theme files are much simpler, in terms of defining them. Those guides recommend using AAAPackageDev, which is not necessary (and not compatible with ST3 last I checked). The language files are all XML, which you can work with, but I find working in JSON or YAML easier. If you feel the same way, you can start with the below snippet and use [SerializedDataConverter](https://github.com/facelessuser/SerializedDataConverter) to convert between XML and PLIST/JSON.

```
{
    "name": "Syntax Name",
    "scopeName": "source.syntax_name",
    "fileTypes": [""],
    "patterns": [
    ],
    "uuid": "ca03e751-04ef-4330-9a6b-9b99aae1c418"
}
```

I can't recall the location of any references, but I'm sure they're out there. Though, simply viewing some existing theme files may be enough for you. TO view these, you can use [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer). Isn't really necessary if you are working in ST2, but makes things much easier in ST3. To begin working on your own custom theme, I'd copy the contents of the theme file you are currently to a new file, and save it in your Packages/User directory. That way, you always have something to revert to, in case you mess something up.